# Using search, find function across mutiple columns

Tags: excel

I am new to excel so let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I have a cell I wish to display "yes" based on if another 3 cells contain "yes". Only if this 3 contain "yes", then the cell will be "yes"

Columns N to Ps should be "yes", the nT would be "yes". See on the image.[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op3C5.png

I´ve tried

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(N2:P2,{"*si*"})),"si","")
=isnumber(FIND("si",N3-P3))
=isnumber(FIND("si",N3:P3))
```

It works but I can´t find the way. to command specifically that all 3 rows should be yes

Answer (score 0):

Simple IF function

```
=IF(AND(N2:P2="si"),"si","")
```

EDIT: This is an array formula, so you may need to enter it using Ctrl+Shift+Enter (CSE)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that the other answer from Jodi would work on all versions of excel (It doesn't on mine).

This should work if you wanted it on each row

```
=IF(AND(N1="si",O1="si",P1="si"),"Si","Nope!")
```

If you have excel spill range functionality, you could put this in the first row, and it would spill down to your other cells.

```
=FILTER(IF(P:P<>"Si","",IF(O:O<>"si","",IF(N:N="Si","Si",""))),N:N<>"")
```

[Sample file here.](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AiO7_3PtXmZ9g6wEpSwSiGsmMzX_mg?e=HcNCOd)

Comment: It should work on all versions. What version do you have?  Did you enter it as an array formula  (with `ctrl+shift+enter`) and does it show braces `{..}` around the formula in the formula bar?